# Make a vim command act on a visual selection OR the whole buffer

Tags: vim

I have this vim function/command that formats json

```
function! JSON()
  %!python -m json.tool
  setlocal ft=json
endfunction

command! Json call JSON()
```

I want to improve it to:

- if it's called on a visual selection replace the selection with the formatted code, and don't `setlocal ft=json`
- if no range is given do what it did before

I suspect I have to use the `-range` flag on `command!`, but couldn't figure out how to adapt the function to only replace the current selection.
Also couldn't figure out how to make it act differently depending on whether a range is given or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mostly a matter of combining `:help command-range` and `:help function-range`.

First, let's simplify the problem a little by removing the `&filetype` logic:

```
function! JSON()
    %!python -m json.tool
endfunction
command! Json call JSON()
```

Now, let's use `-range=%` so that the command operates on the given range or on the whole buffer by default:

```
function! JSON()
    %!python -m json.tool
endfunction
command! -range=% Json call JSON()
```

Then, let's call the function with the given range:

```
function! JSON()
    %!python -m json.tool
endfunction
command! -range=% Json <line1>,<line2>call JSON()
```

modify it so that it knows how to handle a range:

```
function! JSON() range
    %!python -m json.tool
endfunction
command! -range=% Json <line1>,<line2>call JSON()
```

and finally, use the range within the function:

```
function! JSON() range
    execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!python -m json.tool'
endfunction
command! -range=% Json <line1>,<line2>call JSON()
```

For the last part, let's take a look at the `&filetype` logic. The only way to know if the function operates on the whole buffer or not is to compare `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` with the first and last lines of the buffer. We must do that before using the formatter because its output might have a different number of lines than the given range.

```
function! JSON() range
    if a:firstline == 1 && a:lastline == line('$')
        setlocal filetype=json
    endif
    execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . '!python -m json.tool'
endfunction
command! -range=% Json <line1>,<line2>call JSON()
```

And we are done.

Comment: In principle, formatter is allowed to output different number of lines than input, so it makes sense to put "if" before "execute".